# MySQL NULL Requests, MySQL PID Not Found

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sleep, pid

I use PDO as my DB wrapper to connect PHP to MySQL. Also I'm sure that my connection will be closed after my goal reached and expected queries done. For more info I have to say that my connection is not persistent and my platform is CentOS.

Now to explain problem I have to say that when `PROCESSLIST` checked I recognized that there are lots of `NULL Info` with `Sleep Command` processes in the list.
Another problem is after a few minutes or rarely few hours MySQL PID gone. I found that when system didn't work properly and after running command `service mysql restart` I face these statuses:

```
MySQL server PID file could not be found!              [FAILED]
Starting MySQL...                                      [  OK  ]
```

If I have to feed more information please tell me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: A closed connection will release all the resources on the server it uses unless you have a query that's still running. Those need to be forced to stop with `KILL` and I'm not aware of any feature in PDO or any ORM for that matter which does that automatically. Don't forget a proper ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) will handle this for you automatically.

Comment: @tadman thanks for answer but I'm wonder why my query would still running, because I cant see my connections and queries in phpmyadmin processlist. I should try.

Comment: What I'm saying is if you aren't running a query and you're not connected you shouldn't be using any resources. `SHOW PROCESLIST` itemizes all of the connections, active or otherwise. It's worth noting that an idle connection doesn't really use a lot of memory or CPU, but if you have a very limited number of connections you do want to close any that aren't actively used.